# Replacing part of webpage with javascript - good?

Tags: javascript

Is it a good programing practice to replace a layout component with another without a refresh?

e.g. say i want to sort items. Is it a good idea to sort them using javascript without any refresh, or should i make a refresh and call php to sort the data?

**EDIT**: I understand the way asked, this question is too open. We got two ways to do things.

**Server side:**

a) depends on server and users with 128MB ram pc will have no issues.

b) requires resources (bandwidth and cpu power) on the server side, while makes the user wait for the page to load.

**client side:**

a) done like a magic. if the user got an i7 cpu it will work like magic. Also no resurces wasted and no wait time.

b) if the user got a slow pc, will it take time for the action to be performed? Say, I want to use javascript to replace 50 small images (icons) and 300 textfields. Should i do this with javascript or php? If the user got a 2000 pc, will he notice a delay or something?

Comment: It's not good or bad -- it just depends on what you want your user experience to be like.

Comment: it's a lot better UX not to reload the whole page. this is because refreshing is sync, and ajax is async; not a lot of folks realize this, but it matters to the user. you can do something else on the page while the ajax loads a new sorted set of rows, but if you're waiting on a php submit the page is frozen and redrawn, losing cursor focus and any un-saved user-entered data in the process. can you imagine having to restart Excel to recalc? who would buy that?

Comment: I'd have to test it out to be sure, but my gut tells me that the AJAX call and client-side DOM manipulation won't be too terriblely slow in the PC circa 2000s, given the work load you describe. Of course, "too slow" is relative to what the user is used to given the state of the rest of the web. What I mean is, all the other sites are doing similar things right now, too. Your site will perform similar to the others.

Answer (score 3):

Almost every AJAX call you make is going to manipulate the DOM with Javascript. I think it largely depends on what you are trying to accomplish, but I don't think there is a reason to force the user to do an entire round trip to the web server if there isn't a good reason to.

Comment: so which one forces a round-trip?

Comment: The php only server call is the "round-trip". Though javascript is using php to do the same thing. What they mean is there is usually no reason to reload the entire page. AJAX is how most of the web works now and is pretty awesome.

Comment: Technically they both go back to the web server. "Round trip" usually implies a full postback, though. The question is how much data is going across the wire, and how much work the browser has to do to render the resulting changes. If you do a full postback, the browser will have to download the whole page again. If you do an AJAX call, presumably only data is being sent back. Then your Javascript uses that data to manipulate only the parts of the DOM that need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, you can answer this question with whether or not you want the sorting done server-side or client-side. If you want client-side then stick to the JavaScript, otherwise go Server-Side. Depending on how big the sort is/ hardware support/ etc. you may want to keep it client-side.

Now, if you use php, or some other language, and refresh the page, then you will have to require the user to redownload the page to see the new content. If this doesn't matter then do it that way.